# How to execute queries to the database in Opa?

Tags: opa

I've declared a database where the customer data is stored:

```
type Customer = 
{
  name : string
  email: string
  cp: int
}

db /customer : Customer
```

I would like to execute certain queries to work with the data such as:

```
Select name where id > <number>
Select * where cp IN(<number>, <number>)
Select * order by name
```

It is possible to execute a function which returns an Array, Map, or similar to iterate it?
How could iterate such a result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to begin with your `db` declaration declares a *single* customer, not a *collection* of customers, which is what you want to do, I believe. I'd suggest to declare it as a map from customer numbers to customer data as:

```
db /customer : intmap(Customer)
```

Now with `customers = /customer` you can get the complete collection of customers and do arbitrary processing on it. Alternatively `Db.intmap_fold_range` gives you a fold function on a range of keys from the collection; with that you can easily code your first query as:

```
names_with_ids_gt(x) =
  get_names(names, id) = [/customer[id]/name | names]
  Db.intmap_fold_range(@/customer, get_names, [], x, none, (_ -> true))
```

Of course getting full collection of customers and doing some processing on it will not be very efficient. For a more efficient solution you will need to use an external database and its querying capabilities. Opa support for those is coming *very soon*: http://blog.opalang.org/2011/11/opas-database-and-where-its-heading.html.